# MCLP uri_id, how to specify an attribute of xml tag in an aggregate xml

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

I was wondering if it is possible to have the uri of document that is being loaded to extract form an xml tag attribute in an aggregate xml ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<trialRecordsOutput>
  <serviceExecutionTime>427</serviceExecutionTime>
  <Trial id="10006">...<Trial>
  <Trial id="123456">...<Trial>
</trialRecordsOutput>
```

In the above example, I am extracting each `<Trial>` as a separate document and I want the document uri_id to be the attribute `id` in the `<Trial>` tag is this possible ? following is sample of my mlcp options

```
-input_compressed
true
-input_compression_codec
gzip
-input_file_type
aggregates
-output_permissions
rest-reader,read,rest-writer,update
-output_uri_prefix
/cortellis/trial/
-output_uri_suffix
.xml
-aggregate_record_element
Trial
-uri_id
__XXXX How to specify XML attribute XXXX__
-transform_module
/com.marklogic.hub/mlcp-flow-transform.xqy
-transform_namespace
http://marklogic.com/data-hub/mlcp-flow-transform
-transform_param
"entity-name=trial,flow-name=input-trial,flow-type=input,job-id=trial_initial_load"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the transform module(mlcp-flow-transform.xqy), you can create a uri that you want by utilizing the attribute Id.

In the return statement, put a new key with name 'uri' to $content. As we add 'value'.

```
let $uri := 'Your new uri'
let $value := 'Your actual content'
return (map:put($content,'uri',$uri),
     map:put($content,'value',$value))
```

For more information refer to Chapter 4 of the MLCP user guide [Importing Content Into MarkLogic Server - XQuery Implementation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_74640)

Comment: 'mlcp-flow-tranform.xqy' is a DHF code. I don't have access to it.. all I can do is replicate it as I do need the DHF input flow workflow